# how to stop reading when not expecting any message

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

in the below code we asynchronously wait to receive data. But how to stop waiting for read when not expecting anymore data. 
The reason I'm asking this is because I want to implement a class which keeps listening to arriving messages in a separate thread using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe and want to terminate listening once my test gets over (in order to release socket connection).

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def tcp_echo_client(message, loop):
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8888,
                                                    loop=loop)

    print('Send: %r' % message)
    writer.write(message.encode())

    data = yield from reader.read(100)
    print('Received: %r' % data.decode())

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()

message = 'Hello World!'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(message, loop))
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop waiting, [cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) the [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) that runs the coroutine. For example:

```
# tcp_echo_client as in your code

message = 'Hello World!'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(tcp_echo_client(message, loop))
loop.call_later(5, task.cancel)  # cancel the task after five seconds
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    pass
loop.close()
```

If you are using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`, note that it returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object, which itself has a [`cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel) method. Cancellation of the future returned by `run_coroutine_threadsafe` will be noticed by asyncio and result in the cancellation of the task in the event loop thread.

Answer (score 0):

streamreader doesn't comes with any timeout https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/96
so once you start reading you cannot stop.
For me I sent a closing message and handled in my client that on encountering closing message it should not go for further read.
That's how i stopped reading.
Once reader.read is called it keeps waiting for a message (Even after calling writer.close) and keeps the socket engaged until object is destroyed.

Comment: It is not true that once you start reading you cannot stop. For example, you can use `data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(4096), 5)`, and reading will time out in 5 seconds.

Comment: @user4815162342 `wait_for(reader.read(), N)` has its own issues. Been dealing with this in a personal project for a few months now, and unsure what to do myself. See [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue39758).